# Navigation Controller Back button to go to the screen before the previous screen

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, back-button, uinavigationitem, back

I'm wondering whether it's possible to go back to 2 previous page using navigation controller button. Right now, I've custom made the button using this code

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:mainLib.navCountryTitle
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                target:self
                                action:@selector(handleBack:)];
```

And on 'handleback' method, I called this line

`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

So in this case it will go to the previous screen. However I want to go to the screen before the previous screen.

I know that i can call that screen straight away, but I wouldn't want to do that because in every screen I have a back button which supposed to go to its previous screen.

Comment: Look at this answer, it's to the same type of question:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13661751/1869038

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pop to particular viewcontroller using its pushing index. If you know the syntax than you can do that like

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:indexOfViewController] animated:YES];
```

I believe, In your case it would be 1st Index. Though you can again change index and check.

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

Here self.navigationController.viewControllers is the array of the all the ViewControllers pushed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: it is used for me as go back to perticular index in navigation controller.

Comment: @K.D Glad it helped. You can share your happiness by upvote. THax