# How to create Navigation bar with back button on it?

Tags: ios, xcode4, uinavigationbar, xcode4.3, uinavigationitem

I am very new to **iOS App Development**.

In my app I am trying to navigate from second view to first view using navigation bar back button, but while drag and drop the navigation bar in the view I am just able to get the bar with title.

I am really worried and I am not sure what I am doing wrong? I am using **Xcode 4.3.** and storyboard to design the view.

**What i am getting now**

[image: While Drag and Drop the Navigation Bar]

**Looking for**

[image: Looking For]

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: If you're using storyboards, l3v outlines the process. If not, the process is a little different. Are you using storyboards?

Comment: Yes i am using story board.. sorry i will update my question

Comment: @Downvoter shall i know the reason for downvote please

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Xcode handles this for you.**

Highlight your first controller. Go to the menu bar and click **Embed In > Navigation Controller**. Now using `UIButton` or something, control-click and drag from your first view controller's button to your second view controller and make it a **Push segue**. The back button won't appear, but if you run it, it will be there.

So you should have 3 views in storyboard. **The Navigation Controller**, your **first view controller**, and your **second view controller**.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752297) is one way to do it using code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i tried like what you said.. but its doesn't appear on runtime

Comment: Are you going to the second view controller? Or are you just looking at the first?

Comment: actually i am using button to go for second controller.. but now i deleted the button done like what you said but it doesn't going to second controller.. how to do that.. sorry for this simple question

Comment: You still need some way to go to your second controller from your first. So you were right using a button. The back button will appear once you are on the second view. So for testing, just drag a button onto your first view, control-click drag from that button to the second view and choose push segue.

Comment: yes i tried that it just blank with out any titlebar or backbutton

Comment: Click on your navigation controller and make sure 'Shows Navigation Bar' is checked in attribute's inspector. Do neither views have a navigation bar, or just the second?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14525/discussion-between-l3v-and-vinoth)

Answer (score 3):

if you want to get a plainButton in the navigation like the iphone`s backButton (only one view), you must add image, i think there is no other way.Of course , if you have 2 or more viewcontrollers , you will use navigationItem.backBarButtonItem without add image .But the first viewcontroller do not have the backButton.

the code like this:

```
navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Detail"] autorelease];

        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 30)];

    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plain.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithCustomView:button];

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonItem;

    [buttonItem release];
    [button release];
[navigationBar pushNavigationItem:navigationItem animated:NO];
[self.view addSubview:navigationBar];
```